Implied correlation smile
i'm currently reading the book of S.BOSSU ADVANCED EQUITY DERIVATIVES.
He is currently speaking about the implied correlation smile.

My question is : is it a sentiment indicator as the volatility smile or the correlation option market is too small and there is no feedback effect for this space ? And the excess in correlation in fixed strike are a leading indicator ?
Many thanks

By implied correlation do you mean the correlation between the Wiener processes for a stochastic vol model?

I mean the expecting average correlation as stated by cboehttps://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://cdn.cboe.com/resources/indices/documents/Cboe_USO_ImpliedCorrelation_0421_v2.0.2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiQi_bmiPqIAxVsTKQEHcSzKZ8QFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2ZzUog5cXRx51fe5_OExmt

Your link doesn't work.

my bad https://cdn.cboe.com/resources/indices/documents/Implied_Correlation-WhitePaper.pdf

There are no correlation options used in computing the correlation index. You already linked the paper, which shows it simply uses index options and options of the constituents (50  tracking portfolio stocks with adjusted weights to be precise).
At the end of the paper can see the big spike around COVID. That holds generally though and a higher implied correlation means that the market expects the individual stocks in an index (or assets in a portfolio) to move more closely together, often in the same direction. That is usually the case in times of distress.
What the index itself will not show (and I am also not sure your figure 8.1 displays) is a correlation skew. I don't know the book but it looks like a standard IV and also does not state it's implied correlation.
In any case, higher implied correlations for out-of-the-money (OTM) put options suggests investors expect that in a market downturn, stocks will be highly correlated, which in turn  can indicate bearish sentiment and fear of systematic risks.
https://cdn.cboe.com/resources/indices/documents/Cboe_USO_ImpliedCorrelation_0421_v2.0.2.pdf has a graph showing the historical implied correlations for various deltas. As you can see, the 90 delta implied correlation was 1 during the COVID downturn and the CBOE document also states that

90 delta Implied Correlation, for example, quantifies investor
expectations about the likelihood of negative systemic shocks

